# SystemUpdate() inside my remote event receive will raise "Access denied. You do not have permission to perform this action or access this resource."

Tags: development, csom, updatelistitems, remote-event-receiver

I have the following code inside my remote event receiver (which run on item added):-

```
 using (ClientContext context = TokenHelper.CreateRemoteEventReceiverClientContext(properties))
            {
              currentItem["OrderAssignToApprover2"] = new FieldUserValue() { LookupId = spUser.Id };
              currentItem.SystemUpdate();
```

now if a non-admin user add an item then the remote event receiver will raise this error  on the SystemUpdate():-

```
Access denied. You do not have permission to perform this action or access this resource.
```

but if admin user add an item then the remote event receiver will works fine OR if i change the remote event reicever to run using App Permsion, as follow:-

```
using (ClientContext context = Helpers.GetAppOnlyContext(properties.ItemEventProperties.WebUrl))
            {
              currentItem["OrderAssignToApprover2"] = new FieldUserValue() { LookupId = spUser.Id };
              currentItem.SystemUpdate();
```

so can i assume that the `SystemUpdate()` (unlike `Update()`) require the user to have full control on the site?If this is the case then is there a way to allow non-admin users to execute `SystemUpdate()`?
Thanks

Comment: Does the non-admin user has full control permissions on list item?

Comment: @GaneshSanap no they have contribute permission only

Comment: I think in order to use the `SystemUpdate()` user should have at least edit permissions on the list and list item. try giving edit permissions on list to user and let me know if this works.

Comment: @GaneshSanap i do not want to grant non-admin users Edit, they should only have contribute

Comment: According to [this](http://www.techrobbers.com/2019/10/update-vs-systemupdate-sharepoint.html), to update the item using JSOM/CSOM using system update requires at least edit permission.